# Adding and Editing the data from the same form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-forms

I'm new to react and wanted to know how to update and edit the array data in the same function handleSubmit() from the forms in react by applying conditions

This is my code

```
const Subcontentinfo = () => {

    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([
        { id: 1, firstname: "Mike", lastname: "Huston", surname: "MH", mailid: "mikehustoncorp@live.com", company: "Estra Boutique ltd." },
        { id: 2, firstname: "Richard", lastname: "", surname: "R", mailid: "mikehustoncorp@live.com", company: "Amazonia online" },
        { id: 3, firstname: "James", lastname: "Dustin", surname: "JD", mailid: "mikehustoncorp@live.com", company: "Alibaba Traders .co" },
        { id: 4, firstname: "Amanda", lastname: "Paul", surname: "AP", mailid: "mikehustoncorp@live.com", company: "Estra Boutique ltd." }
    ]);
const [addFormData, setAddFormData] = useState({
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        surname: "",
        mailid: "",
        company: "",
    });
const [editContactId, setEditContactId] = useState(null);

const addData = () =>{
 const newContact = {
            id: contacts.length + 1,
            firstname: addFormData.firstname,
            lastname: addFormData.lastname,
            mailid: addFormData.mailid,
            company: addFormData.company
        }

        setAddFormData({
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            mailid: "",
            company: "",
  setContacts([...contacts, newContact]);
        });
}

editData(){
  const editedContact = {
            id: editContactId,
            firstname: addFormData.firstname,
            lastname: addFormData.lastname,
            mailid: addFormData.mailid,
            company: addFormData.company,
        };

        const newContacts = [...contacts];

        const index = contacts.findIndex((contact) => contact.id === editContactId);

        newContacts[index] = editedContact;
            setContacts(newContacts);
            setEditContactId(null);

}
```

I want addData() and editData() to be in same method(like **handleSubmit()**) by applying condition
This is my button:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} className="data-saving" >Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rather than using two different **State** you can use only one state and do something like that

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        id:  null
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        surname: "",
        mailid: "",
        company: "",
    });


handleSubmit(formObject){
  if(formData.id === null){
    // if "id" is null its mean its a new record
    //... create the unique ID here
  }else{
   //  edit the existing record and update
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update current values in your state you should use array or object destructing based on how you stored data.
In case you have array of objects

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([
   {name: "John", age: 20},
   {name: "Dastn", age: 25}
])
```

To update it (to add `{name: "Doe", age:30}`)

```
const onSubmit = newObject => {
  setContacts(prevState => [...prevState, newObject])
}
```

After that your `contacts` array will become like this:

```
[
  {name: "John", age: 20},
  {name: "Dastn", age: 25},
  {name: "Doe", age:30}
]
```